# Botão do carousel não aparece

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

já tentei procurei erro de tudo que é jeito mas n achei de forma alguma

```
       <div id="carouselFritou" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/500x260" class="img-fluid d-block">

          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="https://placehold.it/500x260" class="img-fluid d-block">

          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselFritou" role = "button" data-slide = "prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselFritou" role = "button" data-slide = "next" aria-hidden="true">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Proximo</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Qual botão seria?

Comment: o botão pra passar para a proxima img

Comment: Ele aparece. Acho que vc não está vendo ele porque ele é branco e o fundo da página pode ser branco também.

Comment: pior que só aparece o do lado esquerdo, o direito não aparece de forma alguma

Comment: imaginei que poderia ser por causa do framework, mas estava erradi

Comment: A largura do carousel é o mesmo da imagem, 500px?

Comment: Eu testei aqui e funcionou normal. Se puder mandar um print da tela pra eu ver.

Comment: Quais botões vc se refere, as setas de navegação ou aos indicadores que fica na parte de baixo indicando em qual slide está? Se possível coloque uma imagem indicando o problema

Comment: Solução está em outro questionamento feito: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249541/change-arrow-colors-in-bootstraps-carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esqueceu de algumas linhas de código. Como por exemplo: Os "li's" que contêm os data-target's, um dos mecanismos principais do Carousel. Segue a correção:

```
 <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/500x260" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placehold.it/500x260" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
 </div>
```

Teste e diga se funcionou!